# SWIFT animation while changing NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

Here is my code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if mapHeight.constant < 400 {
            mapHeight.constant = 400
            tableOfRestaraunts.reloadData()
    }
}

func normalSize() {
    if mapHeight.constant == 400 {
            mapHeight.constant = 200
    }
}
```

when user scrolls UITableView my map becomes smaller, and when he touches anywhere it becomes default size.

I want to add some animation (just so this looks a bit more smoothy). I've tried a few solutions from net, but they hadn't helped. Any tips?

Comment: Checking floating point numbers for equality like this will give you mixed results.  I'm also not clear why you think you need to reload the table view just because a constraint changed--you shouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as always you should call `layoutIfNeeded` to animate a change in a layout constraint. In your case you should call it on the view containing the constraint (which is not immediately obvious to me). Or simple `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the actual animation block:

The example does the animation for you and the animation takes `0.5` second to finish. You can use the overloads of `UIView`'s animation blocks for a better control on your animations' details.

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if mapHeight.constant < 400 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
                mapHeight.constant = 400
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }
            tableOfRestaraunts.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func normalSize() {
        if mapHeight.constant == 400 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in

                mapHeight.constant = 200
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:** I didn't realize you haven't the animation block. Updated to include the actual animation block.

Comment: You don't need to set the `constant` property within the animation block.  That should happen before.  Also, please mind your indentation.

Comment: You're right, but for the sake of visibility, it's better to do it inside the animation block, this way everyone's clear on the purpose and consequences of the animation block. and **Should** is too strong a word for a pattern that will be the same either way, don't you think?